# Getting undefined method `any?' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am following the Michael Hartl ROR tutorial and I am trying to paginate the users followers/following pages and I am getting an error saying undefined method `any?' why is that?

view/users/show_follow.html.erb

```
 <div class="row">
<aside class="span4">
    <section>
        <%= gravatar_for @user %>
        <h1><%= @user.email %></h1>
        <span><%= link_to "view my profile", @user %></span>
    </section>
    <section>
        <%= render 'shared/stats' %>
        <% if @user.any? %>
        <div class="user_avatars">
            <% @users.each do |user| %>
                <%= link_to gravatar_for(user, size: 30), user %>
                <% end %>
            </div>
            <% end %>
    </section>
</aside>
<div class="span8">
    <h3><%= @title %></h3>
    <% if @users.any? %>
    <ul class="users">
        <%= render @users %>
    </ul>
    <%= will_paginate %>
    <% end %>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`any?` works only on Enumerable's. See here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F

I suspect `<% if @user.any? %>` should be `<% if @users.any? %>` instead.